# How do I specify to my custom component where a value is displayed within a input message?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am building a value selector component in ionic/angular however I have one issue with the message/title I am passing to the component.
I would like to be able to specify where the currently selected value is displayed within the message.

I thought about passing some marker like %value% inside the message string to be processed by the component.  However, there must be the more standard approach to handle this?

In the following snapshot I would like the `<ion-badge> {{Value}} </ion-badge>` displayed where the X is.

```
<div class="ValueSelector_Container">
    <div class="Message">
        <ion-label>{{Message}} <ion-badge> {{Value}} </ion-badge> </ion-label>
    </div>
    
    ...
```

[image]

Here is how I am invoking/hosting the current component. I will eventually handle the output of the actual selected value

```
 <ValueSelectorComp Message="Play X minutes before switching to bla bla" ></ValueSelectorComp>
```

I have added a code reproduction via stackblitz here it is

[image]

If you have a working fix/suggestion please fork and report the link.  Thank you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fx1ktl?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.13.1 (C:\Users\AXM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0, browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10

npm show ionic version
5.4.16
npm show cordova version
11.0.0
npm show angular version
1.8.2
show @angular/core version
13.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me

home.html

```
<ValueSelectorComp
    Message="Play {{Value}} minutes before switching to bla bla"
    (MessageValue)="valueHandler($event)"
  ></ValueSelectorComp>
```

home.ts

```
Value: number;
valueHandler(val: number) {
    this.Value = val;
  }
```

ValueSelectorComp.html

```
<div class="ValueSelector_Container">
  <div class="Message">
    <ion-label>{{Message}}</ion-label>
  </div>
</div>
```

ValueSelectorComp.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.MessageValue.emit(this.Value);
  }
 @Output() MessageValue: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
```

link:  [stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dvsqjg?file=pages/home/home.ts](http://%20stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dvsqjg?file=pages/home/home.ts)

Comment: I tried to incorporate your code, but getting an error. I never used this "translate" pipe where do I specify it?  Keep in mind I am still in Angular 5.x I cannot move up.

Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected } at the end of the expression [{{'Message'| translate: {X: Value}}}] in ng:///AppModule/ValueSelectorComp.html@8:15 ("
<div class="Message">

<ion-label>[ERROR ->]{{'Message'| translate: {X: Value}}}</ion-label>
</div>

"): ng:///AppModule/ValueSelectorComp.html@8:15
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
<div class="Message">

Comment: Please look at the updated post I have added the following link please fork and reshare your link.  Thank you  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fx1ktl?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: @Meryan:  I have changed logic. Please refer below link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dvsqjg?file=pages/home/home.ts

Comment: Thanks for alerting my brain that ngOnOnit() is not called automatically but the component has to implement onInit.  My brain was hung on the placement of "Value" instead on proceeding with emitting the value back from the component as it has to happen to make the component anything useful.   I have also learned from answer below @Mohammad relating to ng-content.  Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your actual answer text to reflect your solution in your stackblitz link, in other words it's not using {{'Message'| translate: {X: Value}}}

Comment: I have edited. It ({{'Message'| translate: {X: Value}}}) is useful when we use translate service

Answer (score 1):

you can use content projection to pass data

```
<div class="ValueSelector_Container">
<div class="Message">
    <ng-content> <ng-content>
</div>
```

and in parent component

```
<ValueSelectorComp >
 <ion-label>Play <ion-badge> {{Value}} </ion-badge> minutes before 
  switching to bla bla  </ion-label>
 
</ValueSelectorComp>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not yet attempted to follow your suggestion but it appears that the parent is suggesting the internal building block/tags of the component?  I have never used ng-content before.  Would you be kind to fork the following link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fx1ktl?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts  and share your solution link.  Thank you.

Comment: I made this But I don know if this will work for you https://ionic-qhhado.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to ng-content "aka content projection" I have combined it with @dindayal answer which emits the value out of the component.
I like the ng-content approach because it's a bit similar with how I currently layout an ion-range, however when I asked the question I wanted the component to dictate/control the layout so I will stick with that thought. Again ng-content reminds me that there component open/close tags take a content not just attributes :)

Here is a combo approach.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gvpgof?file=pages%2Fhome%2FValueSelectorComp.ts

Answer (score 0):

While I did not explicitly state it as a requirement in the original post my brain was leaning/struggling towards a solution where

1. the component client selects where the value is placed within a message displayed in the component,
2. however the component controls ultimately the choice of the layout and tags used to display the message and value.
3. the Message and the Value are sourced by the client, and the final Value is returned by the component.

To this idea I have hacked the following "solution"

[image]

[image]

The working example is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xzdgyb?file=pages%2Fhome%2FValueSelectorComp.html

In @Dindayal solution the position is dictated by the component client but the component has little control of the layout of value within the message.

In @Mohammad solution both the position and layout is dictated by the component client

I think I have seen DOM/template injection techniques domsanitizer? perhaps that can play a role in the solution but it's not something I can just naturally code :)